# Java FX 8 Popup does not move focus back to application

Tags: javafx

I have a Java FX application in which I show a [Popup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html)  that contains a text field. I intentionally keep this popup visible even when the user clicks away from it. This works fine except for one case:

When the user has focus on the text field in the Popup, then clicks on a separate application, and then clicks back onto the text field. The FX application does not regain focus from the OS. If the user types on the keyboard, the other application will still receive the keyboard input. To work around this, the user has to click on the main FX application window outside of the popup.

The strange thing is that, in debugging, I can see that the text field in the Popup is getting focus, but the OS does not show that the FX application is now in focus. Is there a way that I can force the OS to move focus to my application?

This occurs on Windows and Mac. I tested with jdk 8 update 45 and jdk 8 update 92.

I did a test with a minimum Popup:

```
static class TestPopup extends Popup {
        TestPopup() {
            content.add(new TextField("Hello"))
        }
    }
```

and I show it by calling:

```
new TestPopup().show(somePaneInMainWindow, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that this is expected behavior.

Answer found here:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8123137

From the link:

> This is the right behavior. All the JavaFX popup windows are
>   unfocusable, so they can receive input only if the owner window is
>   currently focused. Usually popups are set to auto hide, when the owner
>   gets unfocused, but this is not the case in this test, so the popup
>   just stays around.